# How to automatically generate TypeScript files using JavaScript files and their test cases?

Tags: javascript, typescript

AFAIK, there is no tool which automatically converts JavaScript files into TypeScript files with meaningful information (e.g. accurate type annotations other than any for all).  If given JavaScript files and their test cases, is it possible to generate the better quality of TypeScript files?  For example, I can imagine one can modify a JavaScript engine to dynamically annotate the original JavaScript files by running test cases.

Answer (score 0):

All javascript files are valid typescript files.  So there wouldn't be anything to convert.

The closest thing I could think of would be something that could read javascript annotations and use those to create a typescript files (which would just be the javascript file with variable types included).

Here is some information regarding annotations since it seems to be on topic for this questions.  [JS Annotations](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#overview)